# Quarkus auto init h2 db for test end local dev purposes

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, quarkus, quarkus-panache

In project we use [quarkus](https://quarkus.io/guides/).

We need oracle db for production, but for local development and for testing we need `h2`. `h2` is new one for this project. To manage this way we've configured

```
# mock for oracle db
%local.quarkus.datasource."oracledb".db-kind=h2
%local.quarkus.datasource."oracledb".jdbc.driver=org.h2.Driver
%local.quarkus.datasource."oracledb".jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:default;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
%local.quarkus.hibernate-orm."oracledb".database.generation=drop-and-create
%local.quarkus.hibernate-orm."oracledb".datasource=oracledb
%local.quarkus.hibernate-orm."oracledb".packages=ourproject.model
%local.quarkus.hibernate-orm."oracledb".dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
%local.quarkus.hibernate-orm."oracledb".log.sql=false
%local.isbn.suffix=LOCAL
```

also we added java configuration dependent on active profile

```
@IfBuildProfile("local")
@Dependent
public class StartUpLocalConfiguration {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(StartUpLocalConfiguration.class);

    @Inject
    @DataSource("oraclemock")
    AgroalDataSource oraclemockDataSource;

    void onStartForLocal(@Observes StartupEvent event) {
        System.out.println();
        LOG.info("[START] H2 DB initialization for local dev environment where profile: %s"
                .formatted(ProfileManager.getActiveProfile()));

        List<String> createdTables = createAndInitTablesFromCsvDirectory();

        LOG.info("[END] H2 DB initialization for local dev environment where profile: %s"
                .formatted(ProfileManager.getActiveProfile()));

        // Logging data from specified tables
        System.out.println();
        LOG.debug("[START] Printing data loaded from H2 DB after it's initialization");
        for (String tableName: createdTables) {
            printTableData(tableName);
        }
        LOG.debug("[END] Printing data loaded from H2 DB after it's initialization");
    }

 ...
}
```

After that we can easily work using oracle schema (old approach works perfectly) and h2 db (if profile is `local`).

Local java configuration loads data to db perfectly, also it verifies the result (data loading and verification is done over `jdbc`).

### Problem

In case we manage db operations with hibernate (application completely started and initialized with newly added configuration) it leads to next issues for `local` profile

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The default datasource has not been properly configured. See https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource#jdbc-datasource for information on how to do that.
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.common.runtime.AbstractJpaOperations.getEntityManager(AbstractJpaOperations.java:62)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.common.runtime.AbstractJpaOperations.getEntityManager(AbstractJpaOperations.java:51)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.common.runtime.AbstractJpaOperations.find(AbstractJpaOperations.java:198)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.common.runtime.AbstractJpaOperations.find(AbstractJpaOperations.java:193)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.common.runtime.AbstractJpaOperations.list(AbstractJpaOperations.java:241)
```

### P.S.

The default datasource (for oracle one) left with no changes:

```
quarkus.datasource."oracledb".db-kind=other
quarkus.datasource."oracledb".jdbc.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
quarkus.datasource."oracledb".jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@dburl
quarkus.hibernate-orm."oracledb".datasource=oracledb
quarkus.hibernate-orm."oracledb".packages=ourproject.model.entities
quarkus.hibernate-orm."oracledb".dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
quarkus.hibernate-orm."oracledb".log.sql=false
```

entities configured with [hibernate-orm-panache](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache)

Comment: How are you injecting your EntityManager to use hibernate? As you're using one specific database setting the "oracledb" on the properties name, I think you need to tell hibernate that you're not using the default data source and you are using the "oracledb". Something like @Inject
@PersistenceUnit("oracledb") 
EntityManager entityManager; But if you are not using multiple data sources in your project, perhaps you could just remove the "oracledb" from your properties, like change from `quarkus.datasource."oracledb".db-kind=other` to `quarkus.datasource.db-kind=other`

Comment: @felipe-windmoller `@DataSource("oracledb")`. i have few datasources in the same project thus i need specified configuration `quarkus.datasource."oracledb".db-kind=...`

Comment: I've done a test using Quarkus 2.7 with Panache and everything worked. [Panache with Repository pattern](https://github.com/felipewind/poc-quarkus-multiple-datasources/blob/main/quarkus-vrs-2-7-panache-repository-pattern/README.md) and [Panache with Active Records pattern](https://github.com/felipewind/poc-quarkus-multiple-datasources/blob/main/quarkus-vrs-2-7-panache-active-record-pattern/README.md). If you need to inject the EntityManager, I guess you should use the @PersistenceUnit("oracledb") annotation, like [this guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm#multiple-persistence-units).

Comment: When reading the error `The default datasource has not been properly configured.`, looks like that there's some problem with your quarkus.hibernate-orm."oracledb".packages definition. Apparently, the Entity you're using is not in the same package declared with "oracledb", so Quarkus tries to find the default datasource to use with your Entity.

Comment: The `default datasource` would be the one defined without the `"oracledb"` in the name, like `quarkus.datasource.db-kind=other
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@dburl
quarkus.hibernate-orm.packages=ourproject.model.entities
quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.sql=false`.